# Yo CorDapp does not run against 4.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: corda

After some trivial tweaks in `build.gradle`:

- `corda_release_version` to say, 4.0-SNAPSHOT-sean
- `corda_gradle_plugins_version` to 4.0.23
- `quasar_version` to '0.7.10'

And repositories:

```
maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }  
maven { url 'https://ci-artifactory.corda.r3cev.com/artifactory/corda-releases' } 
maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/kotlin/kotlin-eap/' }
```

And in `deployNodes` task:

- adding `rpcSetting`s to the notary
- removing `finance` from cordapps

The Yo CorDapp can stand up with three nodes: Notary, PartyA and PartyB.

The issue is that after a single `/api/yo/yos` query, the whole thing becomes frozen. All apis come back with `HTTP ERROR 500`, the debugging ports not working, trace logs show some artemis errors.

My setup: java version "1.8.0_172" on macOS 10.31.1.

It would be helpful to get at least the simplest CorDapp to run against the SNAPSHOT.

\Sean

Comment: Are you checking the web logs as well as the node logs?

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything wrong here. We run continuous integration on the `master` branch but (unlike the `release-Vx` branches) we can't make any guarantees about the `master` branch working at any point in time.

I replicated your steps, and in my case, I got the following error:

> [WARN ] 2018-06-14T14:18:22,744Z [Thread-11 (ActiveMQ-server-org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ActiveMQServerImpl$5@d15f031)] core.client.fail - AMQ212037: Connection failure has been detected: AMQ119014: Did not receive data from /127.0.0.1:55037 within the 60,000ms connection TTL. The connection will now be closed. [code=CONNECTION_TIMEDOUT] {}